# Insert Python Datetime into SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas

I'm trying to insert python DataFrame into SQL Server table but I'm getting an error when it reaches the column with Datetime entries.

```
# Insert Dataframe into SQL Server:
for index, row in df.iterrows():
      cursor.execute("INSERT INTO dbo.shablon (id, abbr, reg_date) values (?,?,?)", row.id, row.abbr, row.reg_date) 
conn.commit()
cursor.close()
```

I get this error

> DataError: ('22008', '[22008] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Datetime field overflow (0) (SQLExecDirectW)')

I tried to change date type inside the database into `datetime` and `datetime2` but that didn't help.
Datetime entries in python are like `2013-02-26` or `NaT`. `NaT` must be saved in the database as empty value.

##### UPDATE:

The problem is caused by missing values in the `reg_date`.

Comment: Seems like you're passing in a string representation of a date instead of an actual Python `datetime` object. You will get a similar error in SSMS when executing `set dateformat dmy; select cast('2013-02-26' as datetime);` Try 1) sending a real `datetime` object; or 2) format the string representation as `yyyyMMdd` to be an unambiguous format; or 3) prefixing your insert statement with `set dateformat mdy; `.

Comment: as it appears now,
the problem is caused by missing values in the reg_date.
I want the missing values to be also missing in the database,
I used NaN and NaT but nth helping until now

Comment: If it's not a valid date have you tried using Python's `None` value?

Comment: can’t figure out how to correctly replace NaT to None inside dataframe column

Comment: I guess I found the answer now
`df['reg_date'] = df['reg_date'].astype(object).where(df['reg_date'].notnull(), None)`